# How to convert an array $scope to a json object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an angular array `$scope.items` that I want to convert to a json object. I've been trying to convert it using `JSON.stringify()` but it always returns with a `[]`

Here's my code:

```
$scope.items = [];

var scopeItems = {};

scopeItems = JSON.stringify($scope.items);

console.log(scopeItems);
```

I'm using [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) as a reference in my code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for anyone that can help me!

Comment: JSON.stringify returns you a string not an object. Also, JSON.parse won't convert the array to object. While array itself in javascript is an object

Comment: Well afaik, JSON.stringify([]) is indeed `"[]"` whats strange there

Comment: What result do you expect?

Now you got exactly what you wrote – objects in JSON are surrounded with `{}`, arrays with `[]`.

Comment: It will just return with an empty `[ ]` without any values at all. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify convert an array to string. not to an object. if you want to convert it to an object then use javascript `reduce` like this

```
$scope.items = ["item1","item2"];

var scopeItems = {};

scopeItems  = $scope.items.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(scopeItems);
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

 $scope.items = ["item1","item2"];

    var scopeItems = {};
    
    scopeItems  = $scope.items.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
    debugger
      acc[i] = cur;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(scopeItems);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Thank you! But can I take a little bit more of your time since I really have no idea what's going on with that code since when i read the docs for `reduce` I don't quite get how it works with arrays.

Comment: we call the `reduce`  to iterate over the array and for each iteration it passes 3 parameters. those are `accumulator,currentValue,currentIndex`. if the initial value is available accumulator is equal to the initial value. in here its empty initially, so the `currentValue` assign to the first property of the accumulator (` acc[i] = cur`). then return it

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! It is more understandable to me now. I really appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zyx Sun no problem :D